# can I pass all positional arguments from one function to another in python?

Tags: python, arguments, args, keyword-argument

I have a function from which I would like to pass all arguments to another func.
The following example does not work. how can I pass all positional arguments, and kwargs together, assuming they are not optional (I don't want to collect them as *args and/or *kwargs)?

```
def myfunc(arg1, arg2, arg3 = None, arg4 = None):

    anotherfunc(*args, **kwargs)
```

Thanks

Comment: You will have to do it explicitly, `anotherfunc(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)`. You can't just expect them to magically end up in `*args` and `**kwargs`.

Comment: You should consider just passing a dictionary as a position argument, which will allow you to access all the values by name in the main function, and pass them on in one-shot to the other function.

Comment: @dursk, could you please show me how to do it for my example? Thanks

Comment: @dursk, that wouldn't allow calls like `myfunc(0, arg2=1)`.