# Best Way to Pass Arguments from One Function to Another in Python

Tags: python-3.x, function, arguments

I have a function that performs a specific task, and this function takes many options, both named and unnamed options. For example:

```
def eat_fruit(x,a_number=None , a_fruit=None):
    return(f'{x} ate {str(a_number)} {a_fruit}')
#call the function
eat_fruit("John",a_number=5,a_fruit='apples') #outputs 'John ate 5 apples'
```

Now, I have another function that takes many options, for example:

```
def do_lots_of_stuff(a,b,activity_1=None,activity_2=None):
    return(f'''{a} and {b} {activity_1} and {activity_2}''')
do_lots_of_stuff("Bob","Mary",activity_1='run',activity_2='jump') #returns "Bob and Mary run and jump"
```

I want to have the function `do_lots_of_stuff` call the function `eat_fruit`, sometimes with options. However, it is not clear to me how to pass options from one to the other in a straightforward manner.

Ideally, I am looking for something like:

```
#This code does not work; it demos the type of functionality I am looking for.
do_lots_of_stuff("Bob","Mary",activity_1='run',activity_2='jump', eat_fruit_options={*put_options_here*}):
    eat_fruit(eat_fruit_options)
    return(f'''{a} and {b} {activity_1} and {activity_2}''')
```

Note that this can't be accomplished via `do_lots_of_stuff(*do_lots_of_stuff_options*, *eat_fruit_options*)` since options for `eat_fruit` are not valid `do_lots_of_stuff` options. Furthermore, keyword arguments must come after positional arguments. In addition [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42499656/pass-all-arguments-of-a-function-to-another-function) does not seem to be sufficient here, because I only want to pass some arguments, not all of them.

**Other relevant links (although I don't believe they successfully address my question):**

[can I pass all positional arguments from one function to another in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33128642/can-i-pass-all-positional-arguments-from-one-function-to-another-in-python)

[Passing variables between functions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39962564/passing-variables-between-functions-in-python)

[Passing value from one function to another in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41926716/passing-value-from-one-function-to-another-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
do_lots_of_stuff("Bob","Mary",activity_1='run',activity_2='jump', eat_fruit_args=["John"], eat_fruit_kwargs={"a_number": 5, "a_fruit": "apples"}):
        eat_fruit(*eat_fruit_args, **eat_fruit_kwargs)
        return(f'''{a} and {b} {activity_1} and {activity_2}''')
```

You can pass and forward arguments and keyword arguments. Arguments are in the form of a list. Keyword arguments (kwargs) are in the form of a dictionary, with the key as a string, and the value as the correlating keyword value.